# Issues Scraping the Web with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the web with Python and I am running into some problems.
Here is my code:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pageURL="https://gamesnacks.com/embed/games/omnomrun"
rawPage=request.urlopen(pageURL)

soup=BeautifulSoup(rawPage, "html5lib")

content=soup.article

linksList=[]


for link in content.find_all('a'):
    url=link.get("href")
    img=link.get("src")
    text=link.span.text

linksList.append({"url":"url","img":"img","text":"text"})

try:
    url=link.get("href")
    img=link.get("src")
    text=link.span.text
    linksList.append({"url":"url","img":"img","text":"text"})
except AttributeError:
    pass

import json

with open("links.json","w",encoding="utf-8") as links_file:
    json.dump(linksList,links_file,ensure_ascii=False)

print("the work is done")
```

It gives an error in
`for link in content.find_all('a'):`

I have already tried some online help but it didn't work out.

Comment: Update the question to include the full error message.

Comment: `linksList.append({"url":"url","img":"img","text":"text"})` seems suspicious for me BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `content` as `soup.article` but the `article` is just `None`, therefore you encounter this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    for link in content.find_all('a'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

because `None` itself isn't a BeautifulSoup object so it won't have any of its methods such as `find_all()`.

You need to find a better place for retrieval of the `article` whatever that should be.

Try to use `soup.find_all("article")`, then iterate through it. Perhaps your website contains multiple `article` tags, however, judging by visiting of the website and checking its source I don't see any `<article>` tag anywhere which would be the reason there's no `article` attribute if it were only a single occurrence and would most likely not return anything useful even with `find_all("article")`.